# Zend_Search_Lucene "Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0"

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-search-lucene

I get this error randomly when using Zend_Search_Lucene.

```
Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0
```

Has anybody ran into this who can help?

Thank you.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662159/how-do-i-track-down-an-exception-thrown-without-a-stack-frame-in-unknown-on-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend_Search_Lucene commits data within destructor.

Static variables are destructed later and exception handling engine may be already unloaded.

Use $index->commmit(); before end of script.

Comment: Thanks! there is a typo on `commit` ;)